# How can I check field before selecting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a table like this:

```
// Names
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | visibility |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | Alex   | 1          |
| 2  | Jack   | 0          |
| 3  | Peter  | 1          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I want to select `name`, but I need to check its `visibility` before selecting. In other word, I want it returns name if visibility is `1`, and returns `null` if visibility is `0`. How can I do that in the query?

```
SELECT (check visibility here) AS name FROM Names WHERE id = :id;
```

---

I can do that by PHP like this:

```
if ($result['visibility'] == 1) {
    $name = $result['name'];
} else {
    $name = null;
}
```

But I want to do that by pure-sql.

Comment: you can use `IF` here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `if` which is equivalent to a `case` expression in MySQL.

```
SELECT if(visibility=1,name,null) name FROM Names WHERE id = :id
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
Select  Case When Visibility = 1 Then Name Else Null End As Name
From    Names
Where   Id = :id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with a simple

```
SELECT name FROM Names WHERE id = :id AND visibility = 1;
```

You just have to code your result processing to expect the possibility of getting no rows returned, and that tells you the person is not supposed to be visible, and more over it does not return anything about them

Comment: What is the use of returning NULL in a `name` column. Null tells you absolutely nothing that returning NO results does not tell you

Comment: Look, I have a website like SO, plus my website has a property which lets users to hide their names under their questions. Also I have a query to fetch the questions and all its answers, anyway I know your query isn't useful for me, I think my table structure in the question isn't a good example for reality.

Answer (score 1):

As i comment use the `IF` Condition.

```
SELECT IF(visibility=1, name, NULL) AS name FROM Names WHERE id = :id;
```